# Impacts of violating SRP, Law of Demeter, etc

Tags: oop, unit-testing, design-patterns, refactoring, tdd

I understand that the following is a subjective question but your guidelines would really help me in my pursuit of clean, testable code.

Please consider the following example which, I think, violates a bunch of design principles.

```java
public class OfferEligibilityCheckerServiceImpl implements OfferEligibilityCheckerService, Refreshable{

     private Map<String, OfferCriteria>  offerIdToOfferCriteriaMap;

     private OffersAccessorService offersAccessorService

     public OfferEligibilityCheckerServiceImpl (OffersAccessorService offersAccessorService ){
            this.offersAccessorService = offersAccessorService;
            initValidOfferIdSet();
     }

     protected void initOfferIdToOfferCriteriaMap(){
          offerIdToOfferCriteriaMap = offersAccessorService.get..Criteria();
     }

     //REAL BUSINESS LOGIC, i.e. this is why the service is used by clients!!
     @Override 
     public boolean isUserEligible(String offerId, UserInfo userInfo){
          offerCriteria = offerIdToOfferCriteriaMap.get(offerId);
          return offerCriteria.isEligible(userInfo); // let's not worry about NPE
     }


     // Gets invoked at regular intervals by some scheduler, say Spring.
     @Override // from Refreshable
     public void refresh(){ // ANOTHER responsibility
         initOfferIdToOfferCriteriaMap();
     }
}
```

I feel that the above code is wrong at so many levels but I'm lacking enough in-depth knowledge to convince others that it is mediocre / not testable.

As per my limited knowledge, the problem with the above design is that it looks testable as certain parts can be substituted but it kind of violates all the 'testable design' guidelines.

Conversation between me and others.

1. *Me*: **Complex logic in constructor.**

   *Others*: Nope, I'm invoking a protected method from the constructor which could be overridden if you ever need a test double.
2. *Me*: **Law of demeter violation** - Ask for exact things, not intermediary.

   *Others*: See the power of "Code to Interface". I'm passing in a serviceImpl whereas the constructor expects a Service. So I can always substitute while testing so that the serviceImpl doesn't really talk to a DAO / database during unit tests.
3. *Me*: **Violation of SRP** - Handles business logic, handles let me get my own stuff during my construction, handles let me refresh myself.

   *Others*: That's fine! I don't want to break this class into 3 classes and go through the overhead of scheduling them / wiring them.
4. *Me*: **Mixing Business logic and object construction logic**.

   *Others*: I don't even get you.

***Question 1)***
Am I right?

It might be possible that I'm not pointing out the right problems or not expressing them the right way.

It'd be great if you could list out problems we might face in the future with the above design. It'd be even better if you could address or validate my points  1 to 4.

***Question 2:*** How would you redesign it (including the wiring part)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the problem with design patterns and principles in general - focusing too much on them drives us away from the real purpose of writing code/producing software ... which is to solve business problems.

First, let me tell you why this code is alright:

- it's **simple** (me, as a person unrelated to project can more or less tell what it does)
- it's **small** (20 lines of code for a class solving one issue)
- it's **testable** (as your colleagues mentioned, they can inject stub and test it fine)

Having said that, conclusion is obvious - there's not much room for improvement, except perhaps SRP violation; the refreshing part could indeed be in different component. However, then you'd have two which you'll have to wire together (as also mentioned by your colleagues - which in fact, this class kind of already does). One might argue that's the way to go, but when classes/responsibilities are this small, the effort is usually not worth the benefit and more often than not it introduces unnecessary complexity to code.

Your points 1, 2 and 4 are not the best arguments for redesign. You are right with SRP. But then, your colleagues argument is stronger - breaking such small class into 3 most likely won't do any good and will surely make people ask questions later.

To summarize, it's worth remembering that **somebody at some point will have to read your code**. You need to know when to stop focusing on patterns and perfect design and when to start focusing on making your code as simple for others to follow as it's possible.

Comment: +1:  Except in most OO languages, calling a virtual method from a constructor can be problematic, so I'd worry a bit about point 1.

Comment: Thanks, it was very informative. I actually came up with a simple example but your answer was clear that as those small responsibilities start getting complicated, that's the right time to break it down.

Comment: What would be your thoughts on unit testing above example? One unit-testing class for all responsibilities or one per responsibility / behavior?

Comment: @phani: were the code to remain as it is now, I'd test all with one unit testing class since the behavior is so simple. It'd probably narrow to couple tests, one for `isUserEligible` working on initial state, one for state after refreshing, perhaps one or two more tests for exceptional situations.

Answer (score 2):

1 - Logic in constructor is always a problem, if you are using spring for example your code can fail when sprint creates the service, can be difficult to detect those types of fails, really painful in large codebases.

2 - Something smell bad when you pass an object to a constructor and use this object for extract the real object (the map) you use in your business logic.

3 - IMMO This is the worst smell in the code, the map is used like a "cache", looks that the call to "offersAccessorService.get..Criteria()" its a costly operation that goes to a database or some other persistence mechanism and the map its used to not call this costly operation every time you need to query for and offer, i am right?. If the last its correct, this is a infrastructure concept not a business concept. This code mix infrastructure responsibilities with business logic responsibilities. This things are in the same class but change for different reasons. For example, if you deploy this application in a cluster you perhaps move to a distributed cached system instead of a simple map in memory, in this scenario you need to change this code for an infrastructure concern not for a business one.

4 - Its related to 1 and 3.

Another important concern if that you have mutable state and multithreading, what if the method refresh is called by the background "refreshing" thread at the same a user is calling "isUserEligible"?. Services in spring are (normally you can change this behavior) instantiated once, mutable state in services its very dangerous in multithreads applications.

One posible refactor its separate this infraestructure and business concerns:

```
 public OfferEligibilityCheckerServiceImpl (OffersRepository offersRepository ){
        this.offersRepository = offersRepository;
 }

 @Override 
 public boolean isUserEligible(String offerId, UserInfo theUser){
      return offersRepository.getById(offerId)
             .isEligibleFor(theUser); 
 }
```

The offersRepository its the place where offers are, from the bussinees point of view i don't care what place its, and i don't care it this offers are cached or not, this responsibility goes to the concrete implementation of the repository (repository in terms of Domain Driven Design patterns).